# TabHost Icon expand to maximum size

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I was having some problem by using tabHost.. 
I was trying to insert 5 24x24 png file into tabHost as shown below but the icon expanded to maximum size of tabhost.

Here's my code:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xxx);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xxx);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xxx);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xxx);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xxx);
```

I tired this code but couldn't get what I want.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = (int) (30 * this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

What i get is:
http://i860.photobucket.com/albums/ab166/season04/Capture_zpsrwblmx7y.png

What i want is:
http://i860.photobucket.com/albums/ab166/season04/Capture_1_zpsvwaeu7gu.png

Please help

Comment: Have you tried shrinking the images themselves? That could potentially fix your problem.

Comment: @frgnvola How to do that?

Comment: I mean to suggest that you take the image file itself, and using a photo editor like photoshop, shrink it so that the image appears as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved my problem with this code and xml. =)

```js
private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c, int renewActivity)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);
        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.z_tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.Tab_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);

        switch (renewActivity) {
            case 0:
                spec.setContent(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                spec.setContent(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                break;
            default:
        }
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/Tab_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In case anyone having the same problem as i am. =)